# Why Serversocket.accept() is not answering?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Two different project and i opened two different emulators and i want to communicate each other .I try to open Port with ServerSocket and try to get/set messages between client and server side. i create also Server with c# **for trial** and i can connect that Server but cannot open port with my ServerSocket.

Can you help please? I also saw in debugger this error : `Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)`

Here my Main activity: When i coming on debugger ServerSocket.accept() program returns nothing

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
var serverSocket: ServerSocket? = null
var thread: Thread? = null
var tvIP: TextView? = null
var tvPort: TextView? = null
var tvMessages: TextView? = null
var etMessage: EditText? = null
var btnSend: Button? = null
var message: String? = null
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    tvIP = findViewById(R.id.tvIP)
    tvPort = findViewById(R.id.tvPort)
    tvMessages = findViewById(R.id.tvMessages)
    etMessage = findViewById(R.id.etMessage)
    btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btnSend)
    try {
        SERVER_IP = localIpAddress
    } catch (e: UnknownHostException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    thread = Thread(Thread1())
    thread!!.start()
    btnSend!!.setOnClickListener {
        message = etMessage!!.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }
        if (!message!!.isEmpty()) {
            Thread(Thread3(message!!)).start()
        }
    }
}

@get:Throws(UnknownHostException::class)
private val localIpAddress: String
    private get() {
        val wifiManager = getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager

        val wifiInfo = wifiManager.connectionInfo
        val ipInt = wifiInfo.ipAddress
        return InetAddress.getByAddress(
            ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(ipInt).array()
        ).hostAddress
    }
private var output: PrintWriter? = null
private var input: BufferedReader? = null

internal inner class Thread1 : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        val socket: Socket
        try {
            serverSocket = ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT)
            runOnUiThread(Runnable {
                tvMessages!!.text = "Not connected"
                tvIP!!.text = "IP: " + SERVER_IP
                tvPort!!.text = "Port: " + SERVER_PORT.toString()
            })
                socket = serverSocket!!.accept()
                output = PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream())
                input = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))
                runOnUiThread(Runnable { tvMessages!!.text = "Connected\n" })
                Thread(Thread2()).start()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}

private inner class Thread2 : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                val message = input!!.readLine()
                run {
                    runOnUiThread(Runnable { tvMessages!!.append("client:$message\n") })
                }
                run {
                    thread = Thread(Thread1())
                    thread!!.start()
                    return
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}

internal inner class Thread3(private val message: String) : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        output!!.write(message)
        output!!.flush()
        runOnUiThread(Runnable {
            tvMessages!!.append("server: $message\n")
            etMessage!!.setText("")
        })
    }
}

companion object {
    var SERVER_IP = ""
    const val SERVER_PORT = 5000
}
```

Comment: This is a common mistake. You try to start your server on a port that is already in use. The operating system does not allow that. Search google for `EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)`. Basically what you need to do: 1) find the process that uses the port you want to run your server on; 2) terminate that process.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu But i try to open port with emulator and IP of that is 10.0.2.16 is it ok also for this ip to kill old process

Comment: i found ports with 'netstat -aon' and i killed process and tried again client cannot connected

Comment: Each emulator instance runs behind a virtual router. These routers assign and manage IP addresses in the form of 10.0.2.xx so don't worry about the address. Most likely port 5000 is preoccupied with the system.

Comment: Looks like you have to use network redirection to communicate with your emulator: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#redirection

Comment: If you start your server multiple times and forget to close the listening serversocket you will find your port in use pretty soon.

Comment: @blackapps yes I have two seperate app one Server one Client . I try to communicate each other as in link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sending-and-receiving-data-with-sockets-in-android but cannot connect to Server

Comment: `can send and connect with my client but cannot open port with my ServerSocket.` Impossible. If the server is not listening a client can send nothing. A client should first connect which is not possible if there is no server.

Comment: @blackapps That sentences is bit complex i create also Server  with c# for trial and i can connect that Server with my client from emulator but i cannot use Serversocket via emulator

Comment: @blackapps easy man.. I edited question.. I have one client and one server .Two different project and i opened two different emulators and i want to communicate each other thats it

Comment: @blackapps i did it . So Can you help me ?

Comment: You are not the first who tries to let a client on one emulator connect with a server on another emulator. (Why didnt i read that in your post that you tried that?). This is pretty difficult and needs a lot of network operations before it works. Google. Let them run on two Android devices which is easy. Also a client on your pc can not reach a serversocket on an emulator.